# Which graphic driver(s) should I install?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04

I have an HP OMEN 15 2017 (i7 7700HQ, nVidia GTX 1050Ti) I managed to install ubuntu 18.04 LTS but to boot i used and am using nomodeset tag (otherwise CPU cores get hard/soft lock) which brought my resolution down to 800*600 and uses llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits) for graphics. now the system is functional and everything works now which graphic drivers should i install? i do not want to run nVidia one because it won't really be beneficial to workload nor will i do any GPU intensive work so I want to run my Intel GPU and disable the dedicated 1050Ti which driver do i need to install and if required to be installed to disable nvidia card (BIOS does not have the option)

Comment: hey @karel if i do not add nomodeset at boot CPU gets a soft/hard lock maybe the default drivers are incompatible somehow?

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply but I tested another issue like this in which if  nomodeset is not added at boot the CPU gets a soft/hard lock and installing the recommended Nvidia proprietary driver made the system completely unbootable even with nomodeset. Removing the recommended Nvidia proprietary driver made the system bootable with nomodeset again. Same low resolution too.